# Page stops loading before all image/files are done

Tags: windows, coldfusion, windows-server-2016, lucee

I recently got a new Windows 2016 machine and Lucee (ColdFusion).   Transferring all my clients e-Commerce sites from Windows 2008 CF9.    I am having an issue with all images downloading to the browser.    The images are a bit to large, client not following directions, BUT this was not an issue with the old machine.   If you go to https://shop.bosombuddybags.com/p824/HBB-Custom-Monogram.htm for the first time many of the option images do not load/transfer but the page has stop loading.   They are all there, refresh a few times and they appear use CNTRL F5 and they disappear again randomly.   I have spent 2 days looking through Google searches, and getting no where.   Any suggestions are welcome as this clients had over 1200 options uploaded and having them redo them to make proper thumbs is not an option.    I figure it has to be a Lucee or Windows 2016 setting that I am missing.  As the page stops loading and never loads what ever images were not completed.

Comment: i don;t know if this will help, but when i tried the above page in chrome the images that didn't load showed in dev tools as 403 errors

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Answer (score 3):

Here are the recommendations:

- You have got about 3 or 4 images that are just enormous. Get those down to size.
- Try turning data compression on IIS for static content.
- Try doing some inline images
- Try eliminating some images. Both Font-Awesome and Glyphicons have Facebook and Twitter. You can use them.

Otherwise this is a really show page.

[image]